# Why can't I adjust the font size for Google Fonts?

Tags: fonts

I don't know what is going on here. I linked to the "Rosario" Google font, and I'm trying to get a size of 18px. But no matter what I set the size to, I get the same small font. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus+SC|Chela+One|Quattrocento|Roboto:400,500|Rosario:400,700'

body {

  font-family: 'Rosario', sans-serif;

  font-size: 18px;

  color: #000;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do with how you are defining the url import in the first line.  It should look like this

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9HUg/) showing how you can successfully specify two different font sizes.